# Subir imagen desde React a Node Js y MySQL

Tags: mysql, nodejs, reactjs, multer

estoy en un ABM de Articulos, en el cual quiero cargar la imagen y por un lado cargarla primero en una carpeta dentro del proyecto, y luego cargarla en la base de datos MySQL, el error se me presenta en la primer parte ya que no guarda.. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('image', imgArticulo);
console.log("FORMDATA: " + formdata);
guardarArticulo(
  { descripcion, descripcion_abv, codigo, precio, id_rubro, id_rubro_sub, imgArticulo }, user.token
)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    setCargando(false);
    setCargoArticulo(true);
    toast.success(`Se creo el articulo ${descripcion}`);
    setValues(initialState);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("ERROR : " + err);
  })
```

GuardarArticulo contiene:

```
export const guardarArticulo = async (oArticulo,authtoken) => {
await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_MY_DOMAIN_API_BASE}/api/guardarArticulo`,oArticulo,{
    headers: {
        authtoken,
    }
});
};
```

Desde ahi envio a la api los datos del cual obtengo entre ellos la imagen del file que la ingreso en el formdapata, el input es el siguiente:

```
 <input id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" multiple={false} type="file" hidden onChange={fileUploadAndResize} />
```

Una vez hecho esto la api que recibe los datos esta declarada de la siguiente manera:

```
router.post('/guardarArticulo', authCheck,adminCheck,upload.single('image'),GuardarArticulo);
```

el upload.single es parte de multer:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (request, file, callback) {
    console.log("REQ : " + request);
    callback(null, '../images/prueba');
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix);
}
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

y Finalmente graba en mysql:

```
exports.GuardarArticulo = async (req, res) => {
try {
    console.log("FILEEEEE" + req.file)
    console.log("FILEEEEE" + req.files)
    const { codigo, descripcion_abv, descripcion, id_rubro, id_rubro_sub, imgArticulo } = req.body;
    let articulo = undefined;
    if (req.params.id) {
        let id = await req.params.id;
        articulo = await oCon.EjecutarQuery(`UPDATE articulos 
                SET codigo = ${codigo} , descripcion = '${descripcion}' , descripcion_abv = '${descripcion_abv}'
                id_lista_precio = 0, id_stock = 0, id_rubro = ${id_rubro}, id_rubro_sub = ${id_rubro_sub}
                WHERE id = ${id}`);

    } else {
        articulo = await oCon.EjecutarQuery(`INSERT INTO 
                articulos(codigo,descripcion,descripcion_abv,id_lista_precio,id_stock,id_rubro,id_rubro_sub) 
                VALUES (${codigo},'${descripcion}', '${descripcion_abv}', 0 , 0 , ${id_rubro}, ${id_rubro_sub})`);

    }
    res.json(articulo);
} catch (error) {
    //console.log("!ERROR AL CREAR RUBRO : " + error.toString());
    res.status(400).send('!ERROR AL CREAR/UPDATEAR' + error.toString());
    console.log("ES ESTE ERROR!!!!" + error);
}
}
```